# How to get blob image from mysql to as3 with php and addChild it in a way of getting byteArray and converting it to image?

Tags: php, image, actionscript-3, blob, addchild

How to get blob image from mysql to as3 with php and addChild it in a way of getting byteArray and converting it to image?

this is php:

> ```
> if($RequestType == 'Select'){
>
>   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
>       $arrdata[]=$row;
>   }
>
>   foreach($arrdata as $key=>$value){
>     $output[$key] =  $arrdata[$key];
>     $output[$key]['png'] = base64_encode($arrdata[$key]['png']);
>   }
>
> header('Content-type: application/json');
> print(json_encode($output));
> ```

i've already got something like this, but longer:

> VBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAYxUlEQVR42u1bB3Sc1ZWe8k/vvfem6aPpGk2RZjQzGrVRl6xiyZZkWS4gFxyDGyEsxjE1gVBTSGAdQg4keyCxF4NsY1pCDARsBwiE4pBsIJjN7nKWgM3eJ7/hTDhUIyJyNj7nHh3P/DP/f79373e/e98b0oUXXkj6/2ykfwLwTwAW58br1q0j9fX1UQcGBpgjw0Pcy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In this I'm assuming you have already handled the HTTP request result)

To transform a base64 encoded image to a `DisplayObject`, you first need to decode the Base64 to a `ByteArray` then use the `Loader` class to load the image content, listening for the `Loader`'s `Event.COMPLETE` event to dispatch. Once you've got that event `Loader.content` will contain a `DisplayObject` that you can add to the screen using `addChild()`.

Example: (EDIT: Added an `Array` to keep track of loaded objects in order they were requested and altered function to calls to cope)

```
private var countLoadedImages:int = 0;//track how many images have loaded
private var arrImageLoaders:Array = new Array();//store loaders for call back
    public function loadImageFromBase64(yourBase64:String):void
    {
        var base64:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
        base64.decode(yourBase64);//decode your image

        var data:ByteArray = base64.toByteArray();//convert to byte array

        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadComplete);
        arrImageLoaders.push(loader.contentLoaderInfo);//add to array in order func was called
        loader.loadBytes(data);//hand over to Loader
    }
    protected function onLoadComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        countLoadedImages++;
        event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadComplete);
        if (countLoadedImages == arrImageLoaders.length)
        {
             allImagesLoaded();
        }
    }
    protected function allImagesLoaded():void
    {
        var contentLoaderInfo:LoaderInfo
        for (var x:int = 0; x<arrImageLoaders.length; x++)
        {
            contentLoaderInfo = arrImageLoaders[x] as LoaderInfo;
            addChild(contentLoaderInfo.content);
        }
    }
```

Comment: TO FIX ERROR: "Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:LoaderInfo." - just add as LoaderInfo to event.target.

Comment: `var contentLoaderInfo:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;` Sorry forgot to add the cast statement, this should fix that error

Comment: No problem! =) Just for others. ^_^

Comment: help. when i'm calling, `loadImageFromBase64` in cycle and calling back `contenLoaderInfo.content` it returns wrong image, not first at all. do you know why?

Comment: it sorting images in wrong way. Is that because `loadBytes` is asynchronous method?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that loadBytes is an asynchronous method. To keep track of multiple loads you may need to make use of an `Array`. I'll edit my initial answer to include an example.